# ボタンをクリックしたら、前回クリックしてから 24 時間以上経過しているか条件分岐したい

Tags: php, mysql

やりたいこと
ボタンをクリックしたら、前回クリックしてから 24 時間以上経過しているか条件分岐したい

現在の案
・MySQLのhogeテーブルにdatetime型のlastupdateカラムだけを作成。
・ボタンをクリックする度に、lastupdateカラムを現在時刻で更新して、PHPで24 時間以上経過しているか条件分岐。

質問
・上記案だと、最初だけINSERTして、後は、WHEREにどう書けばよいですか？ idカラムは不要だと思ったのですが必須ですか？
・他によい案はありますか？

Comment: おそらく[XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701)になっている可能性があります。分岐する目的や分岐によって何を行いたいのかを明確にした方が、適切な回答を得られるかと思います。

Comment: タイトル変更しました

Comment: 依然としてやりたいことが分かりません。信用度 6,502 もお持ちの方がこういう質問をするとは思えないのですが、「ボタンをクリックしたら、前回クリックしてから 24 時間以上経過しているか条件分岐したい」というところだけ見て答えると、(1) クリックされたら MySQL の lastupdate から時刻（前回クリック時刻）を取得する、(2) クリックされた時点の時刻（今回クリック時刻）で MySQL の lastupdate を UPDATE する、(3) 前回クリック時刻から今回クリック時刻が 24 時間以上経過しているか否かで処理を分ける・・・ということでいいのではないでしょうか？

Comment: `INSERT` は解るけれど `WHERE` が解らないということであれば、実行する予定の `INSERT` を記載すれば回答が得られ易いでしょう。
他の案を知りたい場合は、`lastupdate` は全閲覧者で共有なのか、 それともログインユーザー毎に自分の値を持つのか、その場合、ログイン認証はどうやっているのか、などの情報が必要なはずです。

Comment: まだ試行錯誤の途中ですが、「UPDATE テーブル名 SET カラム名 = NOW();;」でやりたいことができそうなことが分かりました。これまでidカラムを使用せず、WHEREも使用しないUPDATE文を実行したことがなかったので、こんなDB構成でもよいのか疑問に思い質問しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

実現可能かもしれません。具体的な手順は以下を参考程度に、外していたらごめんなさい。クエリなどコードはゴリゴリ書いてますが環境に合わせてテストしてみてください。

### テーブルについて

- hogeテーブルにはlastupdate（datetime型）カラムのみがあると仮定します。ただし、一般的にはテーブルに主キーとしてidカラムを含めるのが良いかも知れません。どの行か特定する為です。

### SQLクエリ

- 最初の挿入:

```sql
INSERT INTO hoge (lastupdate) VALUES (NOW());
```

- 以降の更新

```sql
UPDATE hoge SET lastupdate = NOW() WHERE id = [対象のID];
```

### PHPによる条件分岐

- ボタンがクリックされた際に、現在時刻とlastupdateの値を比較して、24時間以上経過しているかどうかを判定してみます

```php
$query = "SELECT lastupdate FROM hoge WHERE id = [対象のID]";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$lastUpdate = new DateTime($row['lastupdate']);
$now = new DateTime();
$diff = $now->diff($lastUpdate);

if ($diff->h >= 24 || $diff->days > 0) {
    // 24時間以上経過している場合の処理
    // UPDATEクエリを実行してlastupdateを更新
} else {
    // 24時間未満の場合の処理
}
```